# How to find equation of a cubic function give four random data points?

Tags: calculus, cubics

Given the data points (5.89,40) (6.95,50) (8.22,60) and (9.31,70) how do I find the equation of the cubic function with Maths B calculus techniques? (without matrix) I tried solving it simultaneously, but is stuck on how to eliminate the variables.

Comment: Do the data point lie **exact** on the cubic function?

Comment: Does this help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_interpolation_formula

Comment: Do you mean the $y$ values to be equally spaced?  It is more common for the $x$ values to be.  It will be easier to write $x=f(y)$ because of this.  You certainly can write $y=f(x)$ if you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try again with a set of simultaneous equations but you can apply a couple of transformations first to make them much simpler.

Subtract $(5.89,40)$ from each point and divide each $y$ value by $10$ to get:

$$(0,0)\\ (1.06,1)\\ (2.33,2)\\ (3.42,3) $$

Substitute these points into $y=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ to get your simpler set of simultaneous equations (with $d=0$ immediately!).

Once you've solved to get $a, b$ and $c$, undo the transformations: multiply all of $a,b,c$ by $10$, add $40$ to the equation and swap $x$ for $(x-5.89)$ .

(I hope that transformations of graphs are included in "Maths B calculus"!)

**Edit: help with the simultaneous equations**

Plugging the values into $y=ax^3+bx^2+cx$ we get:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
1.06^3a+1.06^2b+1.06c=1 \qquad  \qquad  \qquad (1\mathrm{a})\\
2.33^3a+2.33^2b+2.33c=2 \qquad  \qquad  \qquad (1\mathrm{b})\\ 
3.42^3a+3.42^2b+3.42c=3 \qquad  \qquad  \qquad (1\mathrm{c})
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Then I’d divide each equation by its coefficient of $c$:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
1.06^2a+1.06b+c=\frac{100}{106} \qquad  \qquad  \qquad (2\mathrm{a})\\
2.33^2a+2.33b+c=\frac{200}{233} \qquad  \qquad  \qquad (2\mathrm{b})\\ 
3.42^2a+3.42b+c=\frac{300}{342} \qquad  \qquad  \qquad (2\mathrm{c})
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Now we can eliminate $c$ by doing equation $(2\mathrm{c})$ minus $(2\mathrm{b})$ and $(2\mathrm{c})$ minus $(2\mathrm{a})$, to get:
$$
\begin{align}
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
1.1236a+2.36b&=-0.0662 \qquad  \qquad  \qquad &(3\mathrm{a})\\
5.4289a+1.09b&=0.0188 \qquad  \qquad  \qquad &(3\mathrm{b})
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align}
$$
... where I’ve rounded the fractions on the right to $4$d.p.

I’ll leave this system of two equations for you to solve now. Once you’ve got $a$ and $b$, plug them into $(1\mathrm{a})$ to find $c$. Good luck!

Comment: can you please show me how to solve the simultaneous equations? I am confused on that part

Comment: I have edited my answer in order to hopefully help!